# Erro ao gerar reCaptcha

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

Recebo uma mensagem de erro:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "https://www.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
>       at :1:16

**Código:**

```
<html>

<body>

<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LcJCIMUAAAAAKV8tUaI2FoVgmoGmksIH16hZmTW'></script>


<script>
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
grecaptcha.execute('6LcJCIMUAAAAAKV8tUaI2FoVgmoGmksIH16hZmTW', {action: 'action_name'})
.then(function(token) {
// Verify the token on the server.
});
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```